# InAppBrowser causing app to crash only on iPhone 5s

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

I'm having an issue where I've got a Cordova app that opens an InAppBrowser and it's crashing on iPhone 5s only.  I can get it to work on iPhone 4s and the simulator fine.  On the iPhone 5s I'm getting the following error:

```
<Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:[appName][0x1412]' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11
```

I have attempted removing the build and rebuilding completely to no avail.  I am using Cordova 3.4 and Xcode 5.1.  Thank you for any ideas or help that you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by using an older version of Xcode, I downloaded and installed Xcode 5.0.1.  You can get it on the http://developer.apple.com site under downloads.